# How do I calculate the third vertex of an isosceles triangle given the other two vertexes?

Tags: geometry

I'm attempting to calculate the third vertex of an isosceles triangle, I know all the angles, the lengths of the sides and the co-ordinates of the points.

As an example, I have two points defined as $(0, 0)$ and $(100, -100)$. I've named the point $(0, 0)$ as $A$ and it has an angle of $45^\circ$, and the point at $(100, -100)$ has been given the name $B$ and also has an angle of $45^\circ$ . I know the distance between the two points $A$ & $B$ is $141.42$ and the other two sides $AC$ and $BC$ have a distance of $100$. I also know my height is $70.71$.

Having all of this data, is it possible to work out what the third point is? The known points and the equal angles are all arbitrary, but always known, so it would be useful for me to have a general solution which works when any combination of numbers are input. Is this possible?

My work on this (so far) is available here: http://codepen.io/danielsamuels/pen/gaNGeq

Comment: If the two points are $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ and the other two sides have length $r$ then you want the two solutions of $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2,\ (x-c)^2+(y-d)^2=r^2$$ which are [given here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28x-a%29%5E2%2B%28y-b%29%5E2%3Dr%5E2%2C%28x-c%29%5E2%2B%28y-d%29%5E2%3Dr%5E2+for+x%2Cy). Note that you must have $$r\ge\frac 12\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}$$ for the solutions to be real numbers.

Comment: For the special case of $45^\circ$, the triangle is $45-45-90$ and the sides are in the ratio of $1-1-\sqrt 2$.  Then points $A,B$ are opposite corners of a square and the points you seek are the other two.  In this case they are $(0,-100)$ and $(100,0)$

Comment: Rory: Thanks for this. are $x$ and $y$ in your equation the final co-ordinates of the third point? I'm having to translate this into software code, so I'm trying to work out how I "plug in" the relevant values.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let the point be $C(x,y)$ now we have A so by distance formula $AB=x^2+y^2=10000 ,BC=(x-100)^2+(y-100)^2=10000$ so by equating two equations you get the $C$ if you have two vertex and distance i hardly think you need other parameters. Hope its clear.

Comment: Where are you getting the $10,000$ from in these formulas?

Comment: @ daniel Distance $100^2$ i have squared it .